# Problems creating progress bar in Visual Studio using MFC

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2005, progress-bar, fill

i'm trying to simply fill a progress bar, full when a check box is checked, and empty when the box is unchecked. there is an ONCLICK action for the check box, so i figured i would check the value every time it was clicked, and would fill the bar only when it was checked.

this code includes a couple different things i tried, anything with progCtrl gave me a runtime error. any thoughts would be helpful, thanks!

```
void Cgui1Dlg::OnBnClickedsetkill()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    //IDC_PROGRESS.Value = 100;
    //CProgressCtrl progCtrl;
    //progCtrl.SetDlgCtrlID(IDC_PROGRESS);
    //UpdateData();
    //if(changefill)
    //{
        //IDC_PROGRESS.PBM_SETPOS(100);
        //SendMessage(IDC_PROGRESS, PBM_SETPOS, 100); 
    //progCtrl.SetPos(100);
    //}
    //else
    //{
        //filled = FALSE;
    //}
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a control variable for the progress control and the check button. Then, do:

```
void Cgui1Dlg::OnBnClickedsetkill()
{
    if(c_Check.GetCheck()==BST_CHECKED)
    {
        c_Progress.SetPos(100);
    }
    else
    {
        c_Progress.SetPos(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1>c:\users\jlehenbauer\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\gui1\gui1\gui1dlg.cpp(210) : error C2228: left of '.SetPos' must have class/struct/union

Comment: How is c_Progress declared? How have you created it?

Comment: c_Progress is the actual variable for the progress bar (mine happens to be IDC_PROGRESS). both it and the check box have been defined in the Resource.h file of my project

Comment: Is that the only error you get? Error C2228 appears if you try to access a non-class or non-struct with a period. For example, when trying to access members of a pointer with '.' instead of '->'. I think it also occurs if the object is not declared, but then you would have error C2065 too (undeclared identifier). That could mean a typo, a missing header...